# I cann't creat new table in sqlite3 from django

Tags: django-models

When I added new string in **models.py** his tables did't create in sqlite3. What I do wrong, again :)

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate  - I did!
```

It's happend, when I don't input templates information after messege:
Please enter the default value now as valid Python.
The datetime and django.utils.timezone module are available so you can do e.g. timezone.now.
I imputed just 1 and enter. After thet it broke.

If you need different information give me know, please.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/meetups/meetup/add/

Django Version: 3.2.8
Python Version: 3.10.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'meetups']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (table meetups_meetup has no column named enormus) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1657, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1540, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1586, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1099, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/meetups/meetup/add/
Exception Value: table meetups_meetup has no column named enormus
```

Errors, when I input: makemigration and migrate

```
(env) PS C:\install\Projects_1> python manage.py makemigrations
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
meetups.Meetup.participant: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'dates' to meetup without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
>>> '2021-10-10'
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'organizer_emails' to meetup without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
>>> test@.test.com
Invalid input: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
>>> 'test@.test.com'
Migrations for 'meetups':
  meetups\migrations\0011_auto_20211026_2116.py
    - Remove field enormus from meetup
    - Add field dates to meetup
    - Add field organizer_emails to meetup
(env) PS C:\install\Projects_1> python manage.py migrate              
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
meetups.Meetup.participant: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, meetups, sessions  
Running migrations:
  Applying meetups.0005_auto_20211026_1234...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\manage.py", line 22, in <module>        
    main()
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 330, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 191, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 324, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 842, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1271, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1266, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1228, in to_python
    parsed = parse_date(value)
  File "C:\install\Projects_1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 75, in parse_date
    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: You're `makemigrations` returned a message to specify the default value for a (new) column, likely you did not fix that, and that explains why the database did not migrate to the latest version of your models.

Comment: You're makemigrations returned a message to specify the default value for a (new) column -Yes I didn't.
(you did not fix that) - How fix that?

Comment: well you need to specify a default for the new column for the existing records, without that, it can not migrate.

Comment: I did that but whithout resoult. New error after "migrate" I added to poste.

Comment: But it looks like `dates` is a `ManyToManyField`, hence `'2021-10-10'` makes not much sense. Can you share the model for which you defined default values?

Comment: `dates = models.DateField()` It was needed?